# Functions/ Loops in python to find a numbers from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there anyway to find the maximum numbers I can choose from a list of numbers and the sum should not exceed 15. Ex: A= [2,5,3,1,10,4,5,9], B=15 output: 5.

I have tried this so far:

```
A,B = map(int,input().split(" "))
A = list(map(int,input().split(" ")))
A.sort()
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'maximum numbers'? All possible combinations?

Comment: Sort the list, then walk the list until the running total is larger than 15.

Comment: Ya but the numbers should not exceed 15 and the output should display 5.

Comment: @chepner is right. sort the list in ascending order then count the # of items you can add up until you exceed 15 and return the counter.

Comment: I have sorted the list, but Im not able to write syntax after sorting.

Comment: Then learn how to code: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/  - that is far more beneficial then copy/pasting answers from SO.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the list. Loop through the list, sum up to current loopindex. If the result is greater then 15, return the previous index.

```
A= [2,5,3,1,10,4,5,9]
A.sort()
for i in range(len(A)):
    if sum(A[:i]) > 15:
        print(i-1)
        break
```

Output:
`5`

Comment: This is inefficient; you don't need to sum up each slice anew on each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

A similar approach to the answer by @J.D. But instead of calculating the `sum` every time, we could use a variable `sum` and add an element each time and check.

```
>>> A = [2,5,3,1,10,4,5,9]
>>> A.sort()
>>> sum = 0
>>> for i in range(len(A)):
...   sum += A[i]
...   if sum > 15:
...     print(i)
...     break
... 
5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Precondition: a must be in monotonically increasing order
def max_numbers(a, b):
    s = 0
    for i, n in enumerate(a):
        s += n
        if s > b:
            return i

print(max_numbers(a, b))
```

Comment: @chepner - you are 100% right :) it should be `return i`

Answer (score 0):

You could also extend on @J.D.'s method and use numpy. You could perform a cumulative sum of the array and then check if the sum to each element exceeds 15.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([2, 5, 3, 1, 10, 4, 5, 9]).sort()

cum_sum =  np.cumsum(a)<16 # returns an array of bools

print(cum_sum.sum())
```

returns:

```
5
```